# vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php at line 646

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, cpanel

hi after upload symfony2 project in the cpanel host :

An exception occurred while executing

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS dctrn_count FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id0 FROM (SELECT n0_.id AS id0, n0_.type AS type1, n0_.annoDate AS annoDate2, n0_.solarDate AS solarDate3, n0_.title AS title4, n0_.body AS body5, n0_.bodyMore AS bodyMore6, n0_.fileName AS fileName7, n0_.user_username AS user_username8 FROM NewsOrNotification n0_ WHERE n0_.type = 1 ORDER BY n0_.annoDate DESC) dctrn_result) dctrn_table:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'darspard_h4mit.NewsOrNotification' doesn't exist 

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'darspard_h4mit.User' doesn't exist 

 in .../vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php at line 646  -+
                    $stmt->execute($params);
                }
            } else {
                $stmt = $this->_conn->query($query);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            throw DBALException::driverExceptionDuringQuery($ex, $query, $this->resolveParams($params, $types));
```

Comment: It says table `NewsOrNotification` does not exist. Did you run the migrations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My development environment on Windows operating system that is not case sensitive but Linux servers are case sensitive. As a result, the renamed table with the same name, entity and my problem was solved. for example :

table newsornotification change name to NewsOrNotification

Answer (score 0):

run `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`. If you can't access to console, upload "ready and clean" database generated on your dev environment